# create sub-dataframe based on substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
    soundIn                 response_rater0  response_rater1    response_rater2
1   audios/VP10_S07_w.wav   2.0              2.0                1.0 
2   audios/VP11_S08_w.wav   1.0              2.0                2.0 
3   audios/VP01_S11_w.wav   1.0              1.0                2.0 
4   audios/VP10_S11_i.wav   2.0              2.0                2.0 
...
```

and I want to create another dataframe with only the rows, that contain 'VP01' in the column 'soundIn'. I tried to do it with loc, but it does not accept that VP01 is just a substring of the item I'm searching for.

```
rslt_df = all_responses.loc['*VP01*' in all_responses['soundIn']]
```

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Try this. Use [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method to run the comparison and pass the result into `all_responses.loc[]` as indices.

```py
all_responses.loc[all_responses['soundIn'].str.contains('VP01')]
```

### Example with Dummy Data

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """
    soundIn                 response_rater0  response_rater1    response_rater2
1   audios/VP10_S07_w.wav   2.0              2.0                1.0 
2   audios/VP11_S08_w.wav   1.0              2.0                2.0 
3   audios/VP01_S11_w.wav   1.0              1.0                2.0 
4   audios/VP10_S11_i.wav   2.0              2.0                2.0
"""

# read data into a dataframe from the string representation
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s+')
# Match serach condition and produce result
result = df.loc[df['soundIn'].str.contains('VP01')]
print(result)
```

**Output**:

```
                 soundIn  response_rater0  response_rater1  response_rater2
3  audios/VP01_S11_w.wav              1.0              1.0              2.0
```